# Can you guys tell me which of these sentence is correct?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

this is the procedures on my lab manual. I've always been wondering. which one is the correct one?

If the weight loss of soil obtained is about <5% (m/m) per 24h, the "soil sample is removed" from the oven.

If the weight loss of soil obtained is about <5% (m/m) per 24h, the "soil sample was removed" from the oven.

This is the original sentence from my lab manual,

If the weight loss of soil is about <5% (m/m) per 24h, remove the soil sample from the oven.

Comment: What is the intended meaning?

Comment: Hello sorry i forgot to put it on my description.

If the weight loss of soil is about <5% (m/m) per 24h, remove the soil sample from the oven.

Comment: The first one is closer. The second refers to some time in the past, but the original sentence seems like an instruction about how to conduct the test.

Comment: The combination of "about" and the "less than" symbol is very strange to me. Using words instead of symbols gives you "about less than five percent" which is almost meaningless. I'd be happy with "less than about five percent" but inserting the inequality symbol before "about" would make the sentence difficult to read.